# Difference in time taken for importing parquet files between SparkR and sparklyr

Tags: r, parquet, databricks, sparkr, sparklyr

I am importing parquet files in databricks using `SparkR` and `sparklyr`.

`data1 = SparkR::read.df("dbfs:/.../data202007*", source = "parquet", header = TRUE, inferSchema = TRUE)`

`data1 = sparklyr::spark_read_parquet(sc = sc, path = "dbfs:/.../data202007*")`

The time difference for import is humongous: 6 seconds for `SparkR` vs 11 minutes for `sparklyr`!
Is there a way to reduce the time taken in `sparklyr`? I am more familiar with `dplyr` syntax and therefore `sparklyr` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `sparklyr::spark_read_parquet` caches the results (`memory = TRUE`).

Compare the following for cached results:

```
SparkR::cache(SparkR::read.df("dbfs:/.../data202007*", source = "parquet", header = TRUE, inferSchema = TRUE))

sparklyr::spark_read_parquet(sc = sc, path = "dbfs:/.../data202007*")
```

And this for uncached:

```
SparkR::read.df("dbfs:/.../data202007*", source = "parquet", header = TRUE, inferSchema = TRUE)`

sparklyr::spark_read_parquet(sc = sc, path = "dbfs:/.../data202007*", memory = FALSE)
```

Comment: Yes! This works great! Referring to my other question on max taking too long, I get the intuition that the max, or other functions like distinct of a column, are taking too long because I had set the memory = FALSE during import here. Are these two connected?

Comment: Also, I read somewhere on github that the slowness of sparklyr during import could be due to inconsistency in the partitioning method between sparklyr and hive. Not that I understand completely what that means. Link on that here https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/1955