# Registering a temporary table using sparklyr in Databricks

Tags: r, pyspark, databricks, sparklyr

My colleague is using `pyspark` in `Databricks` and the usual step is to run an import using `data = spark.read.format('delta').parquet('parquet_table').select('column1', column2')` and then this caching step, which is really fast.

```
data.cache()
data.registerTempTable("data")
```

As an `R` user I am looking for this `registerTempTable` equivalent in `sparklyr`.
I would usually do

```
data = sparklyr::spark_read_parquet(sc = sc, path = "parquet_table", memory = FALSE) %>% dplyr::select(column1, column2)
```

In case I opt for `memory = TRUE` or `tbl_cache(sc, "data")` it keeps running and never stops. The contrast in time difference seems very obvious - my colleague's `registerTempTable` takes seconds whereas my option of `sparklyr` keeps running, i.e. unknown when it will stop. Is there a better function in `sparklyr` for `R` users which can do this `registerTempTable` faster?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using  [`cache`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/R/cache-methods.html) and  [`createOrReplaceTempView`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/R/cache-methods.html)

```
library(SparkR)
df <- read.df("/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv", source = "csv", header="true", inferSchema = "true")
cache(df)
createOrReplaceTempView(df,"df_temp")
```

Comment: Indeed - just 7 seconds. It's pretty fast! Why on earth would this option not be available for sparklyr?

Answer (score 1):

The above works for SparkR.

For sparklyR, you're code the `spark_read_parquet()` with `memory=FALSE` is a pretty similar procedure to what is happening with SparkR.

You shouldn't need to cache the data if you just want to create a temporary table so I would just use `memory = FALSE`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64058553/difference-in-time-taken-for-importing-parquet-files-between-sparkr-and-sparklyr).